# VPN disconnecting after 5 seconds - Routing Tables changed

Tags: mac, vpn, connection, juniper

I saw this post but was unable to respond probably since it's pretty old.

[Cisco VPN disconnects after 5 seconds with error 422](https://superuser.com/questions/28562/cisco-vpn-disconnects-after-5-seconds-with-error-422)

I have the same issue with 2 Macs. One with Yosemite, and one with El Capitan. My older mac with Snow Leopard does not have this problem. Nor does my Windows machine. My El Capitan machine is 2 years old with a fresh os image. (everything else was wiped out)

1. We use Network Connect to connect to VPN.
2. The connection works for 5 seconds.
3. A popup is presented asking for credentials - It says atos needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue.
4. VPN and Internet is disconnected whether I give credentials or not.
5. I have had this problem on 2 different networks. (Century Link DSL and Huges Satellite) The 2 machines (Windows and older Mac) both work from both locations.

We have lots of other Mac users who connect like this without any problems. I can not figure out what is changing the Routing table. I have disabled Bonjour with no success. Firefox and Safari stopped working when I did this.

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Pathfinder has the same problem. See [this page](http://support.cocoatech.com/discussions/problems/31437-atos-needs-to-take-control-of-another-process)

Developer mode must be enabled to get rid of this problem. 
 They suggest to execute sudo /usr/sbin/DevToolsSecurity --enable in Terminal